# What is size (in bytes) of Mbed TLS rsa_context?

Tags: c, rsa, stm32, mbedtls, polarssl

I use MBED-TLS on STM32F103 device. STM 32F103 device  has little SRAM memory (20 Kbytes).

I would like to calculate the ram used by [mbedtls_rsa_context](https://tls.mbed.org/api/structmbedtls__rsa__context.html)

How to do this?
Is it :

> sizeof(mbedtls_rsa_context) + 13 * sizeof(mbedtls_mpi ) + mbedtls_mpi_size (D) + ..... + mbedtls_mpi_size (Vf)

Thanks,

Regards.

Comment: What keeps you from asking your compiler, by using `sizeof()` on the whole thing in one go?

Comment: `sizeof()` will not return the RAM uage that each `mbedtls_mpi` uses on heap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the struct `mbedtls_rsa_context` contains these 13 `mbedtls_mpi` structs, so if you do `sizeof(mbedtls_rsa_context)`, it already includes the `13 * sizeof(mbedtls_mpi )` part. So, no need to add that part.
As for the RAM that each `mbedtls_mpi` consumes, as you can see in `mbedtls_mpi_grow`, the size that is allocated is the number of limbs (x->n) multiplied with chars in limbs (CiL).
If you use `mbedtls_mpi_size` on every mpi, it will just give you the size in bytes that the big integer uses, without the leading zeros, if there are any, which also consume RAM.
Note that this means accessing internal members of the struct, which is not recommended, however there isn't any public API to get that knowledge.

If you are constrained with SRAM, have you considered using ECDSA keys, as same security strength keys consume less RAM?
Regards

Comment: Ron Eldor, thanks for you prompt response. Unfortunately I have to use a 4096 bit RSA key.